# Cannot reverse order because of pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, pagination, will-paginate

I want to order `users` by descending. However, when I add `.reverse` it reverses the `users` a page at a time, not all together.

**show_followers:**

```
<%= render @users.reverse %>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

**Users/_user:**

```
<%= link_to user.name, user %>

<% unless @user.nil? %>

  <% if request.path == "/users/#{@user.id}/listening_to" %>
    <br/>
    <span id="member_since"><%= "Listening Since" %> <%= @user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(user.id).created_at.strftime("%b. %d, %Y") %></span>
  <% end %>

  <% if request.path == "/users/#{@user.id}/listeners" %>
    <br/>
    <span id="member_since"><%= "Listener Since" %> <%= user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user.id).created_at.strftime("%b. %d, %Y") %></span>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
@users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

It seems Rails intelligently orders by the `relationships_create` like I wanted but it's in ascending order. I want the most recent follower to show up on the top of the list.

Comment: reverse isn't something you can call on a relation - thats an enumeration method (I think), when you call reverse, it grabs all the users from the database and reveses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@users = @user.followed_users.reverse.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Reverse at the controller level prior to pagination

Answer (score 2):

In the controller action, you probably have some code that looks something like this: `@users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])`.

You need to put the reverse in that statement, so it looks like this: `@users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('id DESC')` (perhaps with `id` replaced by `created_at`).

Comment: This make the order DESC by when the users were created not by when the following relationship was

Comment: What is the code you're using the in the controller to set the `@users` variable?

Comment: Try `@users = @user.followed_users.desc.paginate(page: params[:page])`?

Comment: I got It! gonna post answer thanks for leading me the right direction